React not applying css from dependency in production build only
I'm using 'intl-tel-input' in my react app.  I've created a component that encapsulates it and imports the necessary css file: import 'intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css
When I run the program with npm start it loads fine and the telephone input looks as it should.  However, when I build it with npm run build, the css doesn't seem to be applied when looking in dev tools and I get just a list of all of the country codes as text.  The build app has the css from the dependency included in the combined main css file, and that file is linked in the index.html. The generated html has the correct css classes and I can pull down the css file correctly from the url in the index.html.
It's a fairly basic react app, the npm build config is basic and the same as what a fresh generated react app with typescript would have. I'm confused as to why the built react app doesn't seem to be applying the css to the component correctly.  Can anyone help me figure out why the css isn't being applied?

How are you running the production build? Did you deploy it to a hosting service or serving it from somewhere?

Ensure that your dependency is listed under the 'dependencies' section of your package.json file, rather than 'devDependencies'.

The project is being served via nginx. The dependency is listed under 'dependencies'.

What CSS/styling is currently being applied in your production build? Can you [edit] to include a [mcve] of the relevant code and server configuration(s), and what debugging details you have collected from the browser?

@DrewReese Thanks for the suggestion on a minimal build for reproducing the problem.  I should have thought to try that earlier, but regardless, your suggestion helped me isolate the issue in nginx, not react.

Welcome, happy to help. I recommend you should still [edit] your post to include a [mcve] of the code so future readers can more easily (1) identify the "question"/"issue" to match to their end and (2) relate to the solution you arrived at that resolved it.

The issue, it turns out was in the nginx config, not react.
nginx was missing include mime.types under http and therefore was returning css as text/plain instead of text/css.
